# Python - Error with boolean condition(?)

Tags: python, return

Hi,

I'm trying to get **return_3**, **return_6** and **return_9** to check if the total value returned from **all_return_values_func** is above 20. The problem is that when I run the script **return_3** it instantly prints "The total number of the returned values are too high".

How come **all_return_values_func/return_value** calculates as being above 20 the first time **return_3** is run?

The point of the script is to go from each of return_3/return_6/return_9 scripts and make each of these functions add to the function **all_return_values_func**, and that functions value is later being checked if above 20 in function **return_value**

```
from sys import exit
import time

def all_return_values_func():
    combined_return_values = return_3() + return_6() + return_9()
    return combined_return_values

def return_value(i):
    if i > 20:
        print "The value is above 20"
        time.sleep(2)
        exit()



def return_3():

    return_value(all_return_values_func)    
    print "Returns integer value: 3 and then jumps to function: return_6"
    time.sleep(2)
    return_6()
    return 3


def return_6():

    return_value(all_return_values_func)    
    print "Returns integer value: 6 and then jumps to function: return_9"
    time.sleep(2)
    return_9()
    return 6

def return_9():

    return_value(all_return_values_func)
    print "Returns integer value: 9"
    time.sleep(2)
    return_3()
    return 9

return_3()
```

Cheers,

Simon

Comment: `return_value(all_return_values_func)` is passing the function `all_return_values_func` to `return_value`, not the return value of `all_return_values_func()`.

Comment: It has no way to work :P 1: `return_value(all_return_values_func)  ` - you are passing function reference ? and then ? comparing it with number ?. 
The number of recursion here is so dam high ? all functions are going to call `all_return_values_func` ? which also calls themselfs ?

Comment: "Return x and then jump to function y" is not something that can ever happen in Python.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
return_value(all_return_values_func)
```

You're not calling `all_return_values_func` so in `return_value()`, you are comparing whether the *function itself* is larger than 20. In Python 2.x, which you are using, this is always true: any function is larger than any integer. (This comparison throws an error in Python 3.x, which is a good deal less mystifying.)

The solution is to actually call the function:

```
return_value(all_return_values_func())
```

However, that's not really a solution, because calling the function will cause the program to enter a recursive loop. `all_return_values_func()` calls `return_3()` which calls `all_return_values_func()` which calls `return_3()` which calls `all_return_values_func()`... Python will throw a `RuntimeError` when the stack hits 1000 calls deep.

Your program doesn't seem to do anything useful, or even make much sense. Perhaps address that before proceeding further.